# I want to Copy the Largest number from one file to another File?But, I cannot find the largest Number

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to take the data taken from a file, convert it to a character array, find the largest number from file first.txt and copy the result to file second.txt. However, when I compile and run the program the following problems occur:

1. Does not take two digit Arrays.
2. It also does not take more than 5 numbers from the text file
3. Whenever I compile the program it writes the last number in the second file.

This is the code I am working with.

```
BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader("first.txt"));
PrintWriter in = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("second.txt"));
char[] array = null;
String str = " ";
str = out.readLine();
array = str.toCharArray();
char max = array[0];

for (char c : array) {
    if(c > max);
    max = c;
    in.write(max);
```

Comment: Why do you convert to characters?
I mean converting to characters is not correct because it won't return you the number. It returns an ASCII code.

Comment: please swap your variables named in and out, they are in the opposite order to what they should be...makes it harder to read :)

Comment: `if(c > max);` should not have the `;` at the end

Comment: If,I don't convert the data from file to characters then how can i Get the data from the file.

Comment: @VishalPanta Use a `Scanner`. It has methods like `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()` and etc which read numbers directly.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not necessary to use char array, better don't. Use String as it is easier in handling. String.split() is a good way to split first.txt and Integer.parseInt() can help you with turning a String to integer. You can store them on an array and sort the array afterwards.

Comment: I tried Your Suggestion and it worked.But,If I give extra space  between numbers error is shown by the compiler.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "27 35 105 49 33 99 24"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at com.example.files.FiletoFileCopy.main(FiletoFileCopy.java:23)

Comment: If there is any solution can u give me some idea

Answer (score 0):

(But,If I try to put Numbers like below-
1
2
3
4
Then it takes only one number that is 1.)

BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Nos for fnding highest.txt"));
        BufferedWriter in = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("third.txt"));
        String str = " ";
        str = out.readLine();
        String []numbers = str.split(" ");
        //array = str.toCharArray();
        //char max = array[0];
        int[] array = new int[numbers.length];
        int count = 0;
        //converting the string to integer format
        for(String strs : numbers){
            array[count++] = Integer.parseInt(strs);
        }
        int max = array[0];
        for (int c : array) {
            if(c > max)
            max = c;

```
        }
    in.write(new Integer(max).toString());
        out.close();
        in.close();
```

Comment: If I give Extra space then this errors are shown.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "27 35 105 49 33 99 24"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at com.example.files.FiletoFileCopy.main(FiletoFileCopy.java:23)